# jquery css and radio buttons

Tags: jquery, css

can some some tell me (and keep in mind I am just playing), why this isn't working:

```
$('.radio input[type="radio"]').css('margin-top', '-5px');
```

All I want it to do is just move the radio box with assign css property up -5px. But it wont do it. And I have seen examples all over the net where this is how you add a property to a css object.

Comment: Is your radio button a child of an element that has the class `.radio`?

Comment: Your code works, assuming your markup matches the `'.radio input[type="radio"]'` selector.

Comment: Please provide your html

Comment: no i will not do that

Comment: How to you expect people to help you if you can't provide a small example of your markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
$('input[type="radio"]').css('margin-top', '-5px');
```

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer